# On Using clojure.tools.namespace

Tags: emacs, clojure, read-eval-print-loop, cider

In emacs cider repl, now I know how to use *clojure.tools.namespace* in a *leiningen* project. However, when I use it on a **single** clj file which doesn't belong to any project, it seems *clojure.tools.namespace* doesn't work on the file:

```
=> #<FileNotFoundException java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate com/foo__init.class or com/foo.clj on classpath: >
```

I have declared *clojure.tools.namespace* in *.lein/profile.clj* and `require` it in the clj file. How should I make *clojure.tools.namespace* work on a single clj file?

### My profile.clj

```
{:user
 {:repl-options {:timeout 128000}
  :plugins [;; REPL
            [cider/cider-nrepl "0.9.0-SNAPSHOT"]
            [refactor-nrepl "0.2.2"]

            ;; Application server
            [lein-immutant "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"]

            ;; Automated testing
            [lein-cloverage "1.0.2"]
            [lein-test-out "0.3.1"]

            ;; Package management
            [lein-ancient "0.6.2"]
            [lein-clojars "0.9.1"]

            ;; Documentation
            [codox "0.6.8"]
            [lein-clojuredocs "1.0.2"]

            ;; Static analysis
            [lein-typed "0.3.4"]
            ;; [jonase/eastwood "0.1.2"]
            [lein-bikeshed "0.1.6"]
            [lein-kibit "0.0.8"]]

  :jvm-opts ["-Dapple.awt.UIElement=true"]

  :dependencies [[org.clojars.gjahad/debug-repl "0.3.3"]
                 [difform "1.1.2"]

                 [spyscope "0.1.4"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.trace "0.7.8"]

                 [org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.9"]
                 [im.chit/vinyasa "0.2.0"]
                 [slamhound "1.5.5"]

                 [criterium "0.4.3"]]

  :injections [(require 'spyscope.core)
               (require 'alex-and-georges.debug-repl)
               (require 'com.georgejahad.difform)
               (require '[vinyasa.inject :as inj])
               (inj/inject 'clojure.core '>
                           '[[clojure.repl apropos dir doc find-doc pst source]
                             [clojure.tools.trace trace trace-forms trace-ns trace-vars
                              untrace-ns untrace-vars]
                             [clojure.test run-tests run-all-tests]
                             [clojure.pprint pprint pp]
                             [com.georgejahad.difform difform]
                             [alex-and-georges.debug-repl debug-repl]
                             [vinyasa.pull pull]])]}}
```

Comment: Could you include the profiles.clj file (you do have an s in the lein.progiles.clj right) and the call to `use` or `require` from the REPL

Comment: `cider-nrepl` already wraps `tools.namespace`. See the `cider-refresh` command.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with tools.nhamespace. The problem is cider doesn't know where to find your source file. This is normally set with the :source-paths option in the project.clj file. By not working with the standard approach of having project directories etc, your really fighting the system and making your life a lot harder than it needs to be. What is your use case for doing this? Perhaps we can suggest a better solution

Comment: @TimX My case here is not very serious. Sometimes, I just want to test some simple ideas, which can be wrapped within one CLJ unit, and a complete project is not necessary. Also, I want to run the CLJ unit with CIDER's REPL.

Comment: Thought it might be something like that. What I do is have a simple base project
called 'scratch' where I do this sort of thing. If it turns out to be an idea with
more 'legs' I then migrate it to its own project. This also stops lots of ancillary
stuff, like compiled classes and other temp files being scattered around my filesystem

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't answer your specific question, it might provide some ideas on
alternative workflows which may help.

- [lein-exec](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-exec) This is a lein plugin that
  lets you write clojure scripts or evaluate clojure expressions on the command line
  in a similar way to what can be done with shells, python, ruby, perl etc. Of
  course, startup time is a bit high, but this plugin will help you deal with
  dependencies etc inside your single clj script file. (there are other possible
  solutions to improve the startup speed). See this blog post for some examples
  http://charsequence.blogspot.in/2012/04/scripting-clojure-with-leiningen-2.html
- A *scratch* project. I have a fairly generic project called scratch. It just allows
  me to create a new file within the src directory of the project which I can use for
  experiments or demonstrations. For example, I have a file called stackoverflow.clj
  within this scratch project which I use when working out the answer to a clojure
  question on stack overflow. In fact, I have a lot of individual clj files in this
  directory, each just representing a simple idea, test, experiment etc. It isn't
  really a project i.e. I couldn't do a `lein run` at the root of the project and
  expect anything meaningful. However, I can go to the source directory in emacs,
  open a file and then run cider.